# Mark lines like overfull

Tags: macros, margins, boxes, plain-tex, latex-misc

I apologize if this has been asked before. I have searched and searched to no avail, it seems questions about getting rid of over/underfull boxes drown out any questions about how to produce the marks.

I have a custom command, and I should like to mark each line that contains this custom command with a marker similar to the over/underfull marker. Ideally it would

- mark the lines in the output when in draft mode
- either not produce warnings on the command line, or produce a custom message detailing the count

pointers, big or small, in the right direction are much appreciated :)

Comment: overfull rule is a primitive feature that can not be emulated by macros, but you could (depending on your use case) use `\marginpar{\vline}` or some other such marker.

Comment: Yay, thanks, that's awesome `\marginpar{\vrule width 5pt}`. Only trouble is the `marginpar` is ignored unless I put something else in with the line. Any tip on an empty/invisible place holder I can use, to ensure the `marginpar` appears in the output?

Comment: you mean like `\marginpar{\vrule width 5pt\leavevmode}`? Sadly the `marginpar` still does not appear :/

Comment: `\leavevmode\marginpar{...}`

Comment: not tested.  unless there's somethiing with height and depth for the `\vrule` to complement, it will have a height and dept of zero, which makes it invisible.  so try following it by a `\vphantom{()}` -- that should give it the height of one line.

Comment: Woohoo! Thanks @barbarabeeton! You hit right on the issue :D The `\vrule` had no height. It is fixed now with `\marginpar{\rule{0.6em}{0.7em}}`. (Your solution with `\marginpar{\vrule width 5pt\vphantom{()}}` works too ;-) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

unless there's something with height and depth for the `\vrule` to complement, it will have a height and dept of zero, which makes it invisible.

i'd probably follow it by a `\vphantom{()}` to give it the height and depth of one line.  you've tried a more latex-y approach

```
\marginpar{\rule{0.6em}{0.7em}}
```

and found it works.

this association of the vertical extent of a rule with whatever is on the
same line was discussed a long time ago in a [tugboat warnings column](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb09-2/tb21beet-warn.pdf) (it's on the second page).  what goes around, comes around.

Comment: Thanks for the extra tugboat link! I hadn't realised that you can in fact specify not only width to a `\vrule` but also height and depth, thus I decided to go with `\marginpar{\vrule width .6em height .5em depth .3em}`